# How to get the predict probability in Machine Leaning

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have this `ML` model trained and dumped so I can use it anywhere. And I need to get not just the `score`, `predict` values, but also I need `predict_proba` value as well.

I could get that but the problem is, I was expecting the probabilities to be between `0` and `1`, but I get something else like below.

```
array([[1.00000000e+00, 2.46920929e-12],
       [1.00000000e+00, 9.89834607e-11],
       [9.99993281e-01, 6.71853451e-06],
       ...,
       [1.22327143e-01, 8.77672857e-01],
       [9.99999653e-01, 3.47049875e-07],
       [1.00000000e+00, 3.79462343e-10]])
```

And this is the `python` code I am using.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


# dataframe = pd.read_csv("hr_dataset.csv")
dataframe = pd.read_csv("formodel.csv")

dataframe.head(2)

# spare input and target variables
inputs = dataframe.drop('PerformanceRating', axis='columns')

target = dataframe['PerformanceRating']

MaritalStatus_ = LabelEncoder()
JobRole_ = LabelEncoder()
Gender_ = LabelEncoder()
EducationField_ = LabelEncoder()
Department_ = LabelEncoder()
BusinessTravel_ = LabelEncoder()
Attrition_ = LabelEncoder()
OverTime_ = LabelEncoder()
Over18_ = LabelEncoder()

inputs['MaritalStatus_'] = MaritalStatus_.fit_transform(inputs['MaritalStatus'])
inputs['JobRole_'] = JobRole_.fit_transform(inputs['JobRole'])
inputs['Gender_'] = Gender_.fit_transform(inputs['Gender'])
inputs['EducationField_'] = EducationField_.fit_transform(inputs['EducationField'])
inputs['Department_'] = Department_.fit_transform(inputs['Department'])
inputs['BusinessTravel_'] = BusinessTravel_.fit_transform(inputs['BusinessTravel'])
inputs['Attrition_'] = Attrition_.fit_transform(inputs['Attrition'])
inputs['OverTime_'] = OverTime_.fit_transform(inputs['OverTime'])
inputs['Over18_'] = Over18_.fit_transform(inputs['Over18'])


inputs.drop(['MaritalStatus', 'JobRole', 'Attrition' , 'OverTime' , 'EmployeeCount', 'EmployeeNumber',
                'Gender', 'EducationField', 'Department', 'BusinessTravel', 'Over18'], axis='columns', inplace=True)


inputsNew = inputs
inputs.head(2)


# inputs = scaled_df
X_train, X_testt, y_train, y_testt = train_test_split(inputs, target, test_size=0.2)
```

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.score(X_testt, y_testt)
print(result)
```

```
loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs) // this produces above result, will put it below as well
```

outpu produces by the `loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)`

```
array([[1.00000000e+00, 2.46920929e-12],
       [1.00000000e+00, 9.89834607e-11],
       [9.99993281e-01, 6.71853451e-06],
       ...,
       [1.22327143e-01, 8.77672857e-01],
       [9.99999653e-01, 3.47049875e-07],
       [1.00000000e+00, 3.79462343e-10]])
```

How can I convert these values or get an output like a percentage? (`eg: 12%, 50%, 96%`)

Answer (score 0):

To convert the probability array from decimal to percentage, you can write `(loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)) * 100`.

**EDIT**: The format that is outputted by `loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)` is just scientific notation, i.e. all of those numbers **are** between 0 and 1, but many of them are extremely small probabilities and so are represented in scientific notation.

The reason that you see such small probabilities is that `loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)[:,0]` (the first column of the probability array) represents the probabilities of the data belonging to one class, and `loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)[:,1]` represents the probabilities of the data belonging to the other class.

In other words, this means that each row of the probability array should add up to 1.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do but why I get output like `[1.00000000e+02, 5.55022984e-12]` for the probability?

Comment: Why they are extremely small probabilities because model produces a score of 95% of accuracy. So the probability should be closer to one right? And how can I convert these scientific notations to the normal percentages?

Comment: The first column corresponds to the probability of the sample belonging to the first class, and the second represents the probability that the sample belongs to the second class, apologies for not making that clear, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Then I want to get the highest probability and convert it into a percentage. Can you help me on this?

Comment: To turn the whole array into percentages, use `100*(loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs))`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: As you can see it is not working. because these values are in scientific notation. I don't understand why we should multiply it by 100 and does it correct the problem. This is my output after multiplying by 100 -> `[1.00000000e+02, 5.55022984e-12]` which still doesn't give what I want.  Can you precisely give an answer to convert these scientific values to A PERCENTAGE LIKE `10%`, or `90%`, a value like this, please? Just don't say to multiply by 100, as it doesn't work  because it produces again `[1.00000000e+02, 5.55022984e-12]`

Comment: As mentioned by @Mohammad Akhtar, perhaps you could write:
`rounded_probabilities = np.round(loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs), n)`, where `n` is the number of decimal places you require.

Answer (score 0):

`loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)` outputs the probability of 1st class as well as 2nd class (as you have 2 classes). That's why you see 2 outputs for each occurrence of the data. The total probability for each occurrence sums up to 1.

Let's say if you just care about the probability of second class you can use the below line to fetch the probability of second class.

```
loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)[:,1]
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, apologies if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: after doing that why I get output like `[1.00000000e+02, 5.55022984e-12]` for the probability? And still, I didn't get my answer yet on how to make these values looks like `10%, 50%, 76%, 95%` and so on?

Comment: As suggested by @Cyber you can multiply by the output by 100 {code: np.round(loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)[:,1]*100,2) } to get values in percentage up to 2 decimal place. I have assumed here that you care about the probability of the second class.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if the result is distributed in a different class and for the right class only you want probability in percentage.

```
pred_prob = []
pred_labels = loaded_model.predict_proba(inputs)
for each_pred in pred_labels:
    each_pred_max = max(each_pred)*100
    pred_bools.append(pred_item)
probability_list = [item*100 for item in pred_prob]
```